# Proving that a function is invertible

Tags: calculus, functions, hyperbolic-functions

> Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ where $f(x)=\dfrac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2}$ . Prove that $f$  is invertible.

Attempt:

To prove that a function is invertible we need to prove that it is bijective.

The slope at any point is $\dfrac {dy }{dx}= \dfrac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$

Now does it alone imply that the function is bijective?  How do I proceed from here? I am unable to write the proof formally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to show that

- f is injective and it is guaranteed if f is strictly increasing
- f is surjective and for that we can use limits to $\pm \infty$ and IVT

Comment: Thanks, Any alternatives to IVT here? , I dont know about IVT yet

Comment: The concept is very simple since f is continuous and the range is all R f is surjective. To prove formally we need intermediate value theorem. As an alternative write y=f(x) and isolate x=g(y) then the function g(x) is the inverse.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: we get $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}>0$$ thus $f(x)$ is monotonously increasing and injective and invertible.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is your function, then $f'(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}2>0$. So, $f$ is strictly increasing and therefore injective.

And, since $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)=\pm\infty$, it follows from the intermediate value theorem that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: I do not know about the IVT, could you suggest any alternative method to prove surjection?

Comment: @Abcd Sure. For each $y\in\mathbb R$, solve the equation $f(x)=y$. Youll get $x=\log\left(y+\sqrt{1+y^2}\right)$.